# Flash Transparent Stage without using wmode?

Tags: flash, background, transparent

Guys for some weird reason im facing a problem that actually surprise me how simple and yet how hard is to overcome.

I have a swf file that i want to embed in a webpage, i use swfobject, but i need the stage to be transparent, because its sitting in relation to other elements and the background has to be unified. I have no problem with

```
wmode=transparent
```

but in Chrome the performance hit is monstrous. I get something like 5-10fps and its completely unusable (no such problem with opaque/direct modes)

Is there a way to make a transparent stage (either through HTML or in the fla settings) without using wmode?